# How to update to Xcode 12 without using App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm currently using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.
Because of Apple's recent update about Xcode - all the app submissions need to be in Xcode 12 starting from April 26th, 2021, I have to update my Xcode.
The problem is that my Mac has total space of 120 GB and currently 13 GB is available - I've tried to clean everything unnecessary.

Since most recent Xcode required Big Sur OS which was also problem for me because of low storage, I'm trying to update my current Xcode via downloading XCode 12.4 which can be run from Catalina from the Apple developer site.

After I downloaded xip file, I couldn't unzip it because of low storage.
In this case, is there a way to install Xcode from the external harddrive or should I remove current XCode in my Mac and unzip it? If I remove current XCode 11, will there be any problems such as losing data?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an answer for this beyond get a new Mac that has more storage. There *are* certain options, but these *will not* overcome Apple's requirements. First, how "imminent" is your need to submit an update to Apple. I did submit using Catalina back in January (and could until last Monday - something that was well known). Until you *need* to submit something, use Xcode 11. Next, can you download the SDKs that Xcode 12.x needs? I was able to do this (for a month or two) with Xcode 11 on a pre-Calaina MacBook, but lost the ability to build certain things like drag and drop....

Comment: Finally, if you simply *cannot* afford to upgrade your hardware for some reason, consider getting an external SSD. The prices are relatively cheap. Consider this the price you have to pay to have your apps available. (Bonus note? remember that starting with Catlina - and MUCH harder with Big Sur, particularly on a Mac with Apple Silicon, it's no less a PAIN to create a bootable backup.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by moving the xip file to the external hard drive and unpack it in there and move it back to mac.